# Cleanest way to generate stars in EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

Using ejs in Node.JS (templating) what's the cleanest and most efficient (in terms of typing) way to generate this kind of html for stars?

stars look like:

```
                <div class="ratings">
                    <p class="pull-right"> reviews</p>
                    <p>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

I'm trying to avoid using some disgusting syntax like this:

```
                <div class="ratings">
                    <p class="pull-right"> reviews</p>
                    <p> 
                            <% for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %>
                                    <% if (i < (star_rating - 0.5)) { %>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <% } else { %>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                    <% } %>
                            <% } %>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much you can do about the for loop, but the code inside it can be reduced by 4 lines using [ternary/conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator:

```
<div class="ratings">
    <p class="pull-right"> reviews</p>
    <p>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star<%= (i < star_rating - 0.5)? '' : '-empty'%>"></span>
        <% } %>
    </p>
</div>
```